# Keep grunt running after logout from terminal

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a way to keep grunt running after login out from the terminal/server.

I was wondering if there is a way to keep grunt compiling forever. Eg: if i close my terminal grunt will still watching the less file and converting them into css

I been following this: http://justinklemm.com/grunt-watch-livereload-javascript-less-sass-compilation/

But he don't mention anything about how to keep the job running after logging out

Answer (score 0):

You can use screen for this.

install the GNU screen package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install screen (on Debian based systems)
$ yum install screen (on RedHat based systems)
```

start the screen and execute `grunt` in it.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

Comment: @Liccy how do you start grunt on windows?